# How do I count the number of times a sequence occurs in a Java string?

Tags: java, string

I have a String that looks like:

```
"Hello my is Joeseph. It is very nice to meet you. What a wonderful day it is!".
```

I want to count the number of times `is` is in the string.

How can I do this in Java?

Comment: Could you post what you've tried yourself? And what about: _"Is miss bliss?"_

Comment: @Bart Kiers then Im sure we could just look for " is " instead of "is" to avoid that ;)

Comment: "you don't understand what it *is*."

Comment: By looking for _" is "_, you'll miss: _" is,"_ and _"is!"_ etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
int index = input.indexOf("is");
int count = 0;
while (index != -1) {
    count++;
    input = input.substring(index + 1);
    index = input.indexOf("is");
}
System.out.println("No of *is* in the input is : " + count);
```

Comment: @jzd agreed, thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: @asgs, I have removed my down vote.  Thanks for the fix.

Comment: @jzd thanks, but you better put that comment back so that the OP or someone else learns from this.

Comment: @asgs, you can't undelete comments and because you edited your answer within the first five minutes there is not revision history.  So there is nothing to learn.

Comment: Works like a charm. Does not require any fancy libraries. Thanks.

Comment: You could also use index = input.indexOf("is", index+1) instead of substring and then indexOf. W/o profiling, I don't know for sure, but suspect this will be quicker. It's also 1 line less of code ;)

Comment: Many false positives like "miss", "bliss". It also misses the capitalized "Is", "IS" or "iS". So although the OP has accepted the answer, a -1 from me.

Answer (score 33):

An easy way is using [Apache StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) `countMatches`

```
StringUtils.countMatches("Hello my is Joeseph. It is very nice to meet you. What a wonderful day it is!", "is");
```

Comment: or with Spring Framework StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf(string, "is");

Comment: Aren’t Spring `StringUtils` meant primarily for use within the framework? Meaning, it works, but Apache’s clearly better in this respect.

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer regex, here is a regex solution:

```
String example = "Hello my is Joeseph. It is very nice to meet you. isWhat a wonderful day it is!";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\bis\\b").matcher(example);

int matches = 0;
while(m.find())
    matches++;

System.out.println(matches);
```

In this case the "is" in "isWhat" is ignored, because of the \b boundary matcher in the pattern

Answer (score 2):

```
String haystack = "Hello my is Joeseph. It is very nice to meet you. What a wonderful day it is!";
haystack.toLowerCase();
String needle = "is";

int numNeedles = 0;

int pos = haystack.indexOf(needle);

    while(pos >= 0 ){

      pos = pos + 1;
      numNeedles = numNeedles + 1;

      pos = haystack.indexOf(needle,pos);

    }

 System.out.println("the num of " +needle+ "= " +numNeedles);
```

Comment: Since when is a variable of the `char` type able to hold multiple characters?

Comment: Noted my mistake and edited

Answer (score 1):

This takes into account the length of "replace"

```
String text = "a.b.c.d";
String replace = ".";
int count = (text.length()- (text.replaceAll(replace, "").length())) / replace.length();
System.out.println(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

split on every " " (blank) and check the outcoming string[] with a loop

Comment: What if there was a space in the string he wanted to check for?

Comment: In that case he wouldn't count the number of "is" in the string >_< , but if so, he could use a regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the [code here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?s=7546cc48e21a2a9727c814ca0bc864fc&p=4700527&postcount=5).
It strangely looks like the Robby's one.