# Attaining the correct number of 'a' characters in the String

Tags: java

I am trying to write a small program that takes a `String` sentence (given in `main method`), and calculates the number of upper case characters and number of a's.  I am having a bit of trouble with the second part.

While there are no doubt multiple ways to write the program, I have written `for loops` that trace through the `String`, and do my work.  It works fine for calculating the uppercase values, but for the a's, it is counting every letter as one.  I may be going crazy.

```
public class CountCharacters {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        charCount("How many UPPER CASE letters, a's, and 0-9 digits are there in this String?"); 
    }

    public static void charCount(String b) {
        int upper = 0;
        int a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
            char v = b.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(v)) {
                upper++;
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
            char t = b.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isLetter('a')) {
                a++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("There are " + upper + " upper case letters, and " + a + " lower case a's in the String");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: `Character.isLetter('a')` always returns true, because 'a' is a letter :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I count the number of times a sequence occurs in a Java string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223815/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-times-a-sequence-occurs-in-a-java-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are testing

```
if(Character.isLetter('a'))
```

74 times.

The lowercase letter 'a' is the lower case letter 'a', every time.  :)

Use

```
if(t == 'a'  ||  t == 'A')
```

or

```
if(Character.toLowerCase(t) == 'a')
```

I think the former is a bit more efficient (and clearer), but either is good.

As pointed out in the comments, since you are not using `t` anywhere else, you can test the character directly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
   if (b.charAt(i) 'a')) {
      a++;
   }
}
```

And you can significantly reduce your code:

```
public static void charCount(String b) {
   int upper = 0;
   int a = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
      char v = b.charAt(i);
      if(v == 'a'  ||  v == 'A')  {
         a++;
      }
      if(Character.isUpperCase(v))  {
         upper++;
      }
   }
   System.out.println("There are " + upper + " upper case letters, and " + a + " lower case a's in the String");
}
```

According to the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase%28char%29), `Character.isUpperCase(c)` only returns true for uppercase letters.

Answer (score 2):

Just use regex:

```
int upper = b.replaceAll("[^A-Z]", "").length(); 
int a = b.replaceAll("[^a]", "").length();
int digit = b.replaceAll("\\D", "").length();
```

These lines each replace all characters you're *not* targeting with a blank (thus removing them), leaving you with only the target characters, then of course you use the length of what's left.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your expression:

```
if (Character.isLetter('a'))
```

That will always evaluate to true.

You want:

```
if (Character.isLetter(t))
```

(Also, you could statically import isLetter and lose the Character prefix for the method.)

Answer (score 0):

There is probably something wrong with the isLetter() method.  Having said that, you don't need it.

```
int upper = 0;
int a = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
    char v = b.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isUpperCase(v)) upper++;
    if (v == 'A' || v == 'a') a++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with one loop -

```
public static void charCount(String b) {
    int upper = 0;
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
        char v = b.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(v)) {
            upper++;
        }
        if (v == 'a' || v =='A') { // <-- check lower OR upper.
            a++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("There are " + upper + " upper case letters, and " 
        + a + " lower case a's in the String");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to loop through the string once:

```
    public static void charCount(String b) {
        int upper = 0;
        int a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
            char c = b.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c))
                upper++;

            if (c == 'a')
                a++;
        }
        System.out.println("There are " + upper + " upper case letters, and " + a + " lower case a's in the String");
    }
```