# Count the no. of occurrence of the exact word in a file using java

Tags: java, string

I have requirement in which I have to find the no. of times a particular word appears in a file.
For eg.

```
String str = "Hi hello how are you. hell and heaven. hell, gjh, hello,sdnc ";
```

Now in this string I want to count no. of times the word "hell" appeared. The count should include "hell" , "hell," all these words but not "hello".
So according to the given string I want the count to be 2.

I used following approaches

1st:

```
int match = StringUtils.countMatches(str, "hell");
```

StringUtils is of org.apache.commons.lang3 library

2nd:

```
int count = 0;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("hell");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
                while (m.find()) {
                    count++;
                }
```

3rd

```
int count =0;
String[] s = str.split(" ");
for(String word: s)
if(word.equals("hell")
count++;
```

the 1st two approaches gave 4 as answer and the 3rd approach gave 1 as answer.

Please suggest anyway in which I can get 2 as answer and fullfill my requirement.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223815/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-times-a-sequence-occurs-in-a-java-string

Comment: Your 3rd approach miscounted because of commas in the text.

Comment: Ya I understood that point, but my files are such that after the words commas, fullstop etc can be there. but I have to consider those words as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use word boundary matchers in regex:

```
Pattern.compile("\\bhell\\b");
```

Comment: This will only return true.  You need to count the matches as well.

Comment: @Ivan I think that was obvious enough.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a regular expression with the "\\b" word boundaries as follows:

```
  int matches = 0;  
  Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\bhell\\b", Pattern.CASE_SENSITIVE).matcher(str);
  while (matcher.find()) matches++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
String str = "put the string to be searched here";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(str);
String search = "put the string you are searching here";
int counter = 0; //this will count the number of occurences
while (sc.hasNext())
{
if (sc.next() == search)
counter++;
}
```

Since sc.next() reads complete next token it will hell and hello will not trouble you.