# How to check if certain sequence of characters exists in char array

Tags: java, arrays

I have two char arrays:
One filled with a certain word. 
For example `char[] word = {'j', 'a', 'v', 'a'};`

the second one is of a given size and is filled with random characters from 'a' to 'z'.

And I need to count how many times a word exists in second array.
For example, assume the second array is: `{'w', 'j', 'a', 'v', 'a'}`
With given example function should return 1, because the word "java" is in the array only once.

Here's my code

```java
    private static int zad4() {
        char[] word = {'j', 'a', 'v', 'a'};
        char[] arr =  new char[100];

        // random characters from a to z
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = (char)('a' + Math.random() * ('z' - 'a' + 1));
        }

        int counter = 0;
        int countWord = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (word[i] == arr[j]) {

                    counter++;
                    if (counter == word.length) {
                        counter = 0;
                        countWord++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return countWord;
    }
```

When I set arr to be same as the word it returned the expected value, but when I set the arr to be `{'j', 'a', 'v', 'a', 'j', 'a', 'v', 'a'};` it returned 3, but I expected 2

Comment: convert char array's to a string, then just follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223815/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-times-a-sequence-occurs-in-a-java-string

Comment: @austinwernli I guess this is homework and the point is working on algorithms (it would be nice if OP stated it, to be fair).

Comment: I need to use arrays because it's homework question regarding arrays. When I could use strings it would be easy

Comment: You should invert your loop: iterate over the arr first, then the word.

Comment: I think you need to go back to the drawing board with this one; your nested loops iterate over every pair `i,j` where `i` is completely independent of `j`. What you're actually doing is counting the number of times a letter at any position in `word` matches a letter at any position in `arr`, with no requirement that the letters of `word` all appear, let alone that they all appear consecutively. Try solving the problem with a pen and paper example first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would make `word` and `arr` method arguments. Generating them locally makes your code very difficult to test and debug. Second, you can increment the count when you have reached the end of the word successfully. Something like,

```
private static int zad4(char[] word, char[] arr) {
    int countWord = 0;
    for (int p = 0; p < arr.length; p++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length && p + i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (word[i] != arr[p + i]) {
                break;
            } else if (i + 1 == word.length) {
                countWord++;
            }
        }
    }
    return countWord;
}
```

Which I tested with

```
System.out.println(zad4("java".toCharArray(), "javajavajava".toCharArray()));
System.out.println(zad4("java".toCharArray(), "javajava".toCharArray()));
System.out.println(zad4("java".toCharArray(), "java".toCharArray()));
System.out.println(zad4("java".toCharArray(), "ja".toCharArray()));
```

Getting (as expected)

```
3
2
1
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Can iterate your arr first, and if the first character matches start the word check.

```
private static int zad4() {
    char[] word = {'j', 'a', 'v', 'a'};
    char[] arr =  new char[100];

    // random characters from a to z
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = (char)('a' + Math.random() * ('z' - 'a' + 1));
    }

    int countWord = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == word[0]) {
            boolean matches = true;
            for(int j = 0; j < word.length; j ++) {
                matches = word[j] == arr[i + j];
                if(!matches)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(matches) {
                countWord ++;
                i += word.length - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return countWord;
}
```