# Method to find substring at given index

Tags: java

I have gone through many threads however was unable to write this logic. I am trying to write a method that would return the index of the last occurrence of a substring in a long string. What am I doing wrong, I am unable to get the right count.

I would like to find how many times "red" is used in this long string. Upon finding the total number, I would like to get the starting index of the last occurrence of the substring I am searching for, in this case, I am searching for "red" which should return the index value 3.

I am able to find the total number of occurrence however cannot figure out how to capture the index of the last substring occurrence. I am new to programming, and have spent couple days trying to figure this out. Thank you for your help. Have a look at my code, see if anyone can point me in the right direction. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    public static int findMatchedIndex(String longString, int atIndex, String subString){
    
        int index = 0, counter = 0;
            while(counter < longString.length()){
                //Setting index at the very first occurence
                index = longString.indexOf(subString, index);

                if(index != -1){
                   //COUNTER IS UPDATED    
                   counter++;  
                   //INDEX IS UPDATED TO SUBSTRING LENGTH
                   index += subString.length(); 
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
            }        
        return counter;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        //RED RED BLUE GREEN ORANGE PURPLE
        String lngStr = "redredbluegreenorangepurple";
        int ind = 0;
        String lookup = "red";        

        int count = findMatchedIndex(lngStr, ind, lookup);
        System.out.println(count);        
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add comments to explain what you think each line is doing in your code?

Comment: It's a bit unclear, are you looking for the nextIndex or the count ?

Comment: ```indexOf()``` returns the index of a character/string in a string, so that only method is doing what you want to do - if I have correctly understand your explanations.
Also, having a ```break``` instruction in a loop is bad practice, in the future, try to identify a condition that could justify the end of the loop instead.

Comment: i think you can refer this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5223843/18845466

Comment: @oliver_feng - thank you so much. I will plug it in and see if it yields the desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comment, if your objective is to get the index of the next occurrence of a substring in a string, the method `indexOf()` does what you want :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hellohello-superman".indexOf("hello", 1));
}
```

Where the output is 5 :). You specify that you want to search starting at 1 (which is an exemple, but basically it would be the value of your `atIndex`), so it would ignore the first "hello", then return 5 becaus eit is the start index of the second occurrence of "hello" in your base string.

EDIT :

To get the number of occurences you could do something like :

```
while(index > 0) { // 4
    index = longString.IndexOf(substring, index); // 1
    if(index != -1) counter++; // 2
    index++; // 3
}
```

Let's understand how it works :

1. First you get the index of your substring in your string.
2. If you get -1, it means that the substring is not in the long string.
3. You update index. Why ? Imagine you search the number of occurrencies of `hello`, in `hellohello` starting with index 2. You would get 5 as an answer. But then, if you don't update it, you would search the occurrence of `hello` starting index 5 and you will get...5 ! And then hello infinite while.
4. Here is the second use of `index++`. You only continue if the index is bigger than 0. Why ? Because if you get -1 in the loop, you will get 0 after `index++` but it still mean that your substring has not been find.

Comment: Thank you Scryper, I have updated the code and reworded what I am trying to code.

Comment: Edited my answer, hope it helps. You'll need to adapt a bit, but the logic is there. The objective is to tell you where to go, but it's better if you finish the work by yourself :)